# @ManagedProperty object for authentication data is null

Tags: jsf-2, annotations

I have the following managed bean which stores the login data after container authentication:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "authenticatedUserController")
@SessionScoped
public class AuthenticatedUserController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private jpa.UtentiportaleFacade ejbFacade;

  public Utentiportale getAuthenticatedUser() {
    if (AuthenticatedUser == null) {
        Principal principal =   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            AuthenticatedUser = ejbFacade.findByLogin(principal.getName()).get(0);
        }
    }
    return AuthenticatedUser;
}
```

getAuthenticatedUser is called in every page because I put the user name in a facelets template on the top right side.
In PermessimerceController, another managedbean,  I need to access login data so it is easy and fast to inject the above session scoped controller:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticatedUserController}")
private AuthenticatedUserController authenticatedUserController;
```

I experienced the following problem: trying to access the page which is linked to PermessimerceController without being authenticated I'm redirected to the login page (and this is OK) but after that I get a null pointer exception because authenticatedUserController is null when it is injected inside PermessimerceController. 
The page in question uses both PermessimerceController and AuthenticatedUserController so I should guess that for some reason PermessimerceController is created before AuthenticatedUserController. Can you suggest a simple way to solve this problem ? 
Alternatively how can I store the login data in an easy to access place ?

Thanks
Filippo

I try to edit this post in the hope to clarify better the problem I have and find useful answers.
Using facelets templating I show the user login name throught a property of AuthenticatedUserController. The rest of the content is linked to PermessimerceController which needs some informations about the user for filtering data. The @ManagedBean annotation is an easy way to accomplish this. Unfortunately if the user access that page without being authenticated the injected AuthenticatedUserController is null. So it seems  PermessimerceController is created before AuthenticatedUserController and I wonder why. Is there a trick I can use for being sure AuthenticatedUserController is create before ?

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for your ManagedProperty in `PermessimerceController`?

Comment: @Matt: that would have resulted in an `FacesException` like `ManagedBeanCreationException`, not a NPE while accessing it.

Comment: BaluC is right, I have the setter for that ManagedProperty.

Answer (score 2):

You were apparently accessing it in the bean's constructor:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{authenticatedUserController}")
private AuthenticatedUserController authenticatedUserController;

public PermessimerceController() {
    authenticatedUserController.getAuthenticatedUser(); // Fail!
}
```

This will indeed not work that way. The bean is constructed *before* the dependencies are injected (think about it; how else would the dependency injection manager inject it?)

The earliest access point is a [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{authenticatedUserController}")
private AuthenticatedUserController authenticatedUserController;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    authenticatedUserController.getAuthenticatedUser(); // Success!
}
```

Comment: What you suggest is what I have already done. If the error was using the ManagedProperty inside the constructor it would always fail. Instead I get a nullpointer exception only if I try to access that page directly (using its unique url) when I'm not authenticated. If I first execute the login and then navigate through the menu to that page the ManagedProperty is not null. It seems there is a race between the creation of the two ManagedBean and cannot figure out why PermessimerceController is created before the other.

Comment: In my first post I spoke about authentication. I forgot to mention that if I'm already authenticated I can access the page linked to PermessimerceController without any problem.